# Tool for generating test case document from javadoc

Tags: java, automation, continuous-integration, maven, junit

I am looking for a tool in Java/maven that can generate test case document from javadoc and merge the test result into it. I am indeed to put the javadoc in front of all integration tests and I want from the tool to generate the according test case document from these information. Also it will be nice if the tool can able to parse the result of the surfire maven plugin in order to modify the state for individual test cases that were generated. As I background information I am using TeamCity for CI and I don't find any plugin for it that can generate a test case document.